# How to read packet sizes in Opus file?

Tags: encoding, packet, opus

I'm encoding a speech sample (in *.WAV format) to *.opus file, using "opusenc" with VBR option enabled. At successful completion of the encoding, the opus encoder returns a report briefing XXX many packets in YY pages and ranges of packet sizes in bytes.

However, I need more information than this. I want to know the actual byte count for each packet in the resulting opus file, of course in the correct order of the encoded packets.

Can anyone help me on achieving the goal with minimal programming? Is there any opus file analyzer or player to provide the information I need?

Comment: Can you show some of your code so that the answers be more specific to your problem

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to get the file size you can try this

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :binary,  :dependent => :destroy
  attr_accessor :file_data
  def before_create
    input = self.file_data
    @binary = Binary.create(:file_data => input)
    self.binary_id = @binary.id
    self.filename = input.original_filename
    self.content_type = input.content_type.chomp
    self.size = @binary.data.size
  end
end
```

Comment: No code yet. Opus is a suite of audio/speech codecs. When it encodes a wave file, it breaks the original *.WAV file into multiple, encoded packets and eventually combines them to a single *.opus file, encapsulating multiple packets of different sizes, and I need to know exact sizes of the packets encapsulated in the *.opus file. This is specific to the standard defined by IETF, and sources are available from: http://opus-codec.org